# WooCommerce Multivendor Marketplace get vendor id from product id

Tags: woocommerce, vendor

I am using WooCommerce Multivendor Marketplace plugin in Wordpress for multivendor site. I want to restrict a user so they can add only one vendor's product in their cart. I am writing a custom function to get vendor id.

I'm trying to use the `get_wcfm_product_vendors` function but it isn't working; I think that it might not be supported. I've search for other possible solutions but I could not find any. Is there any other method I can use to get vendor id for a product?

Comment: I've reformatted your question so that it is more readable and clear; you still need to add context to your question. Please include some source code for the question you have.

Answer (score 0):

You may try WCFM single vendor checkout function, add this code to your child theme :

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', function( $is_allow, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $product = get_post( $product_id );
    $product_author = $product->post_author;
    //Iterating through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $cart_product = get_post( $cart_product_id );
    $cart_product_author = $cart_product->post_author;
    if( $cart_product_author != $product_author ) {
    $is_allow = false;
    break;
    }
    }
    if( !$is_allow ){
    // We display an error message
    wc_clear_notices();
    wc_add_notice( __( "Well, you already have some item in your cart. First checkout with those and then purchase other items!", "wcfm" ), 'error' );
    }
    return $is_allow;
    }, 50, 3 );
```

https://docs.wclovers.com/tweaks/#single-vendor-checkout